# Can you map a key combination to output a specific Unicode character when typing?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, unicode

I am searching for a way (on a Windows machine) how to map a keystroke or multiple keystrokes that produce a specific Unicode character when pressed.

The applications that I found map to a function such as 'run another application', but I couldn't something that lets you map multiple keystrokes to output a string of predefined text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet for this is a key combo mapper like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).